# Can you tour the Port of Singapore?

Tags: tours, singapore

Is there anything that you can see inside the Port of Singapore, or a way to learn more about the port's operations?

Comment: Besides [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_of_Singapore#Operations), for instance?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No**, you can't.  It's a very, very busy working port, full of reversing trucks and cranes flinging about multi-ton containers, many of which contain valuable and/or hazardous cargo.  Short of getting a job, the [only way to enter](https://www.singaporepsa.com/port-users/faq) is to apply for a Temporary Pass, which requires a good reason and a company already operating in the port to sponsor you.

But if you want to get close, you can go for lunch or a drink at the [Republic of Singapore Yacht Club](http://www.rsyc.org.sg/), which is (partly) open to non-members and is located right next to the Pasir Panjang bit of the port.  Alternatively, take a bumboat cruise from Marina South, although I'm not entirely sure these are still operating now that they're building the new cruise centre there.  Most tall buildings nearby will also have good views of the Keppel Terminal, although there's no public observation deck or anything; nobody will stop you from going up into the HDB (public housing) buildings at Spottiswoode Park though.

The best way overall, though, is to watch [this episode of National Geographic's Megastructures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZyBWa3PRtQ) on YouTube.

Comment: The reason you cannot is that they choose not to give tours, and not because it is a very very busy port: the Port of Rotterdam, the busiest port of the World outside Asia, has yearly open days. http://wereldhavendagen.nl/en/

Comment: @DanielSparing But it is the reason you can't just go wander around at random.